# Regex for numbers including decimal and slashes

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string like this:

"`8    R-301            288/313        0.24     TT-2079            347.48`"

Now I want to extract 288/313 and 0.24 using regex So I wrote this:

```python
r42=re.findall(r"8 +R-301.*",pdf[i])
if len(r42[0].split())>3:
  print(r42[0].split())
  logbook['R-301 Temp']=r42[0].split()[2]
  logbook['R-301 P']=r42[0].split()[3]
```

So in an ideal case number comes in 2nd and 3rd index and I can get it.

But the problem I'm facing is that sometimes 288/313 has spaces like this 288 / 313, also the second number 0.24 can have a slash too so it can be like 0.24/0.25 or 0.24 /0.25. So the above regex doesn't work.

What would be an ideal regex for these decimal slash numbers with random spaces?

Note: The string can have multiple spaces between characters.

Edit:

Sorry I forgot one detail here:

numbers can have - like in the above example it can be -/313 instead of 288/313 or - instead of 0.24 or 0.24/- or -/0.24.

Something like this:

"`8    R-301            288/-        -     TT-2079            347.48`"

I want to target those cases as well.

Comment: Minor note, just for clarification, ``\`` is a backslash; `/` is a forward slash (or just a slash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import re

tests = [
    "8    R-301            288/313        0.24     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288 / 313        0.24     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288/313        0.24/0.25     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288/313        0.24/ 0.25     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288 / 313        0.24 / 0.25     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288/-        -     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288/-        0.1 /-     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            -/233       -     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8 R-301 313 -/12123 TT-2079 347.48",
]

r = re.compile(
    r"\s+((?:[\d\.-]+\s*/\s*[\d\.-]+)|[\d\.-]+)\s+([\d\.-]+(?:\s*/\s*[\d\.-]+)?)"
)

for test in tests:
    m = r.search(test)
    if m:
        m = m.groups()
        number1 = m[0].replace(" ", "")
        number2 = m[1].replace(" ", "")
        print(number1, number2)
```

Prints:

```
288/313 0.24
288/313 0.24
288/313 0.24/0.25
288/313 0.24/0.25
288/313 0.24/0.25
288/- -
288/- 0.1/-
-/233 -
313 -/12123
```

EDIT: Updated regex to accept `-`
EDIT2: Updated regex to accept first value without slash `/`

Comment: thanks for the answers, I made a mistake for not adding a detail, Can you kindly look the edit I made

Comment: Thanks man! I works for everything I need it for except scenarios like:
"8 R-301 313 -/12123 TT-2079 347.48"
where there is no slash in the first digit

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, could you please try following regex.

Let's say following are the values:

```
var="""8 R-301 288/313 0.24/0.25 TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 288 / 313 0.24/0.25 TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 288 / 313 0.24 / 0.25 TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 - / 313 -/ 0.25 TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 288 /313 -/ 0.25 TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 313 / - -/ 0.25 TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 288 / 313 0.24/ 0.25 TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 123/313 -/12123 TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 123.12/31.23 -/12123 TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 123/313 -/- TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 123 12123 TT-2079 347.48
8 R-301 -/123 -/- TT-2079 347.48"""
```

Now following is the code:

```
import re
val = re.findall(r'^\d+\s+R-\d+\s+(.*?)T.*',var,re.M)
for i in val:
   re.findall(r'((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|-)(?:(?:\s+)?\/(?:\s+)?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|-))?)',i,re.M)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
['288/313', '0.24/0.25']
['288 / 313', '0.24/0.25']
['288 / 313', '0.24 / 0.25']
['- / 313', '-/ 0.25']
['288 /313', '-/ 0.25']
['313 / -', '-/ 0.25']
['288 / 313', '0.24/ 0.25']
['123/313', '-/12123']
['123.12/31.23', '-/12123']
['123/313', '-/-']
['123', '12123']
['-/123', '-/-']
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex:

```
(                               ##Creating 1st capturing group here.
 (?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|-)            ##In a non-capturing group matching digits with optional dot digits OR followed by - here.
 (?:(?:\s+)?\/                  ##In a non-capturing group with optional spaces with / here.
 (?:\s+)?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|-))?  ##Matching optional spaces with digits and optional digits OR with optional - here.
)                               ##Closing 1st capturing group here.
```

Comment: thanks for the answers, I made a mistake for not adding a detail, Can you kindly look the edit I made

Comment: @WahabAftab, I have changed my code and assumed few examples of lines for your question and tried to cover all cases; please see link https://regex101.com/r/aB2Skb/1/  I have posted code of Python too in my solution, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Imo this is far too complicated - just split on more then two spaces and you‘re done.

Comment: @Jan, this considers that values required in a group(as per OP `I want to extract 288/313 and 0.24`) that's why it has become like that, that's why I asked OP that samples are assumed, let us hear from OP about it else split is much easier then.

Comment: yes its better to be specific in this case as I have multiple lines and need to extract where the pattern is present to splitting on spaces wont be enough

Comment: @WahabAftab, sure. Could you please do let me know if this has helped you? By looking your samples looked like you needed groups kind of result like I shown my python code's output`To access elements of above variable's results as follows:` section). Kindly confirm once, thank you

Comment: @WahabAftab, it's simple, you get values on capturing groups, you access them in list by `0,1,2` and so on and then play around with those values as per your need too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it works for almost all the cases I've tested it on except it doesn't work where there is no decimal in the 2nd digit like this
'8 R-301 123/313 -/12123 TT-2079 347.48'
The idea is the digits can be float and numbers both and can be -  with slashes too

Comment: @WahabAftab, my solution takes cares of / digits floats with your shown samples. I have posted one assumed sample in my answer, please check that one also once could you please give one line here, which is not covered and paste its output too whatever you want to cover also do that it's clear to me, thank you

Comment: line: var='8 R-301 123/313 -/12123 TT-2079 347.48'
output : []

My structure is like this 
a number(8) a code (R-301) info1(123/313) info2 (-/12123) redundant1(TT-2079) redundant2(347.48)
Now the first four elements number,code,info1 and info2 will be present in all cases and reduntant text can be missing in some strings. I want to extract info1 and info2. Now both are numbers and can be decimals and sometimes they are 2 numbers or decimals seperated by slash (123/123.2) and sometimes - is placed instead of number (-) (123/-)(-/1231)(-/0.123)(-/-)(0.123/ -)

Comment: @WahabAftab, ok, please change my regex to `^\d+\s+R-\d+\s+((?:\d+|-)(?:\s+)?\/(?:\s+)?(?:\d+|-))\s+((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|-)(?:\s+)?\/(?:\s+)?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\s+.*$` in above shown command and you are Good to GO, please see this regex Online demo link once https://regex101.com/r/e0lOdV/1 this covers your previous comment's line also, let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: It doesn't work for this :
8 R-301 123.12/31.23 -/12123 TT-2079 347.48

Comment: @WahabAftab, ok, try this out then `^\d+\s+R-\d+\s+((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|-)(?:\s+)?\/(?:\s+)?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|-))\s+((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?|-)(?:\s+)?\/(?:\s+)?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?))\s+.*$` Please check Online demo also in link https://regex101.com/r/jXzbyS/1 once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Hey man thanks, dont need to stay up late, easily can answer tomorrow.
Also these  not working

'8 R-301 123/313 -/- TT-2079 347.48'

8 R-301 123 12123 TT-2079 347.48


8 R-301 -/123  -/- TT-2079 347.48

Comment: @WahabAftab, Please try my updated code once, it has covered all the lines now, thank you. Let me know how it goes?

Comment: @WahabAftab, your welcome, just a tip: from your future questions, please do add detailed samples of your input and expected output, like I added in my answer, that will help to understand question better, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is **far** easier to split on more than two spaces and use the corresponding parts afterwards:

```
import re

tests = [
    "8    R-301            288/313        0.24     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288 / 313        0.24     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288/313        0.24/0.25     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288/313        0.24/ 0.25     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288 / 313        0.24 / 0.25     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288/-        -     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            288/-        0.1 /-     TT-2079            347.48",
    "8    R-301            -/233       -     TT-2079            347.48",
]

rx = re.compile(r'\s{2,}')

for line in tests:
    parts = rx.split(line)
    print(parts[2])
    print(parts[3])
```

Which yields

```
288/313
0.24
288 / 313
0.24
288/313
0.24/0.25
288/313
0.24/ 0.25
288 / 313
0.24 / 0.25
288/-
-
288/-
0.1 /-
-/233
-
```